# Correct workflow for presence subcription for day/night

Tags: rest, lync, ucwa, skype-for-business

In my app, I get Lync Presence of our employees through UCWA. It works fine, but I need to knock to Lync with `reportMyActivity` every 3-4 minute. 
I don't need to get presence info at night when employees are not at work, so I stop reportingMyActivity at the end of the working day and resume at it's beginning. Then trying to extend presence subscription, and if I get 404, I create new presence subscription. But no presence updates after those manipulations.

Is it designed to work this way? How could I avoid `reportingMyActivity` at night?

Comment: A bigger question might be, why does the application need to run at night if people aren't at work as you only state it is looking at presence subscriptions.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please argument your point about this.Shutting down app component responsive for lync integration at evening and running whole procedure (auth, create app, create subsriptions) everyday is obvious, but not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't do `reportMyActivity` your Application will be drained, because assumed inactive.
I think you only have two options then:

1. Keep doing `reportMyActivity` regurarly also at night, you'll just stop extending presence subscription. Very likely you'll have to manage access token expiration too, which is normally 8 hours valid
2. You let the App shut down, and a complete new token acquisition, Application creation, presence subscription flow will start next morning

Comment: what you don't like of my answer, apart from some text formatting)?

Comment: I do like it, it's best so far